# Nested Set Model Maintenance

Tags: mysql, tree, move, hierarchical-data, nested-sets

I am currently developing a comment system for a website that I am working on.  I did a lot of research and decided to use the [nested set model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) to store my comments.  I have created procedures to add and delete comments to keep the left and right values correct.

My question is regarding maintenance of the left and right values.  I am wondering about gaps and the effect they might have over time regarding performance and/or integrity.  I know that gaps are going to end up in the datasets, but I am not sure if this is an issue.  I haven't seen any information regarding maintenance.

Should I create a nightly procedure to sync all left and right values to remove the gaps, or should I not worry?

Comment: i'd be cautious before using the nested set model for a commenting system. obviously i don't understand our requirements etc but i thought this lil warning is harmless enough.

Comment: What issues would the nested set present regarding a comment system.  I thought the nested set model is designed for storing and maintaining hierarchical data?  Especially when there can be an unknown number of child parent relationships.  Is there something else you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave it as is and not worry.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

if it doesn't break anything and it doesn't even create a performance issue it's a non issue.